# How can i Restore the same Database with different name on RDS Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

How can i Restore the same Database with different name on RDS Server its gives me the error like 'DATABASENAME cannot be restored because there is already an existing database with the same file_guids on the instance.'

Comment: is this standard SQL Server? If so you can tell it during the restore what to rename the database to. But I see AWS in the tags so is this an AWS instance? Dont know if its the same there.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they fixed this on RDS for SQL Server instances:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/rds-sql-server-has-two-new-exciting-backup-and-restore-enhancements/

I was able to backup a database to S3 and restore it on the same instance today.

Comment: There is a way to restore it using the same name?  I want to overwrite a database with the one in the backup. It is possible or should I restore it with a different name, change all connection string and then delete the original one?

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, I ended up with the following process:

1. Create a .bacpac (contains both data & schema) of the original DB.
2. Import that .bacpac into a staging database (could be LocalDB, or another instance somewhere, or even the same instance as the original DB).
3. Create a traditional backup (.bak) of the staging DB.
4. Upload the backup to S3.
5. Run the msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database command on the S3 backup file.

Comment: as mentioned by Veldmuis. Now you can do the backup / restore with different db name without restriction.